# Time Series Stationarity

Tags: time-series

While doing time series analysis of data, I see there is clearly a trend as well as seasonality. That means the series is not stationary. DF test confirms the same.

When I did 1 difference in the data, the trend appears to be gone. DF test shows a p-value of less than 0.05 (Meaning data are now stationary).

In this case, do I go ahead and do seasonal differencing as well? Since DF test confirms stationarity, why should I do seasonal adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no stationarity which you asses by plotting the time series and by the [Dickey-Fulle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test)r test, then I don't see how there is any seasonality left in your time series. If there was seasonality you would not have a stationary time series. So as your time series is after the differencing go ahead and fit an ARMA(p,q) model  - essentially you will have fitted an ARIMA(p,1,q) -